# Build Circular Percentage chart

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to build response SVG circular chart, I have succeeded up to some extent.

HTML

```
<div>
            <p class="Project_Analytics_Heading text-center">
                Time per Application
            </p>
            <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">

                <path class="that-circle" stroke="#ffba00" stroke-dasharray="50" d="M18 2.0845
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

                <path class="that-circle" stroke="#ff4858" stroke-dasharray="25" d="M18 2.0845
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

                <path class="that-circle" stroke="#845cee" stroke-dasharray="25" d="M18 2.0845
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

                <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">50%</text>
                <text x="13" y="25" class="percentage_done">iOS</text>

            </svg>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 5% auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 240px;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
}
.that-circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 25px 0 #e5e5e5;
}
@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
}

.percentage {
  fill: #4285f4;
  font-size: 0.375em;
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-family: AvenirNext;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
.percentage_done {
  fill: #9b9b9b;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  font-family: AvenirNext;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}
```

Getting Output

[image]

Desired Output

[image]

I think there is an issue with the stroke-dash array.

Comments are greatly appreciated.

I have referred

https://medium.com/@pppped/how-to-code-a-responsive-circular-percentage-chart-with-svg-and-css-3632f8cd7705

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Charty](http://charty.live) which creates charts without single line of code in seconds.

As per your requirement, try this link, https://charty.live/charts?chtype=doughnutpie&chl=mon,tue,sdf,lkjls,23,LKS&chd=10,9,98,76,23,23,45,65,09,89,78.3&acid=1234&token=5e5ed276f04b0cb0d713a5213f185e1105c83bdd9026076e81e313bb6d94c279

Comment: no we can't use custom charts, we have to use desired chart given by designer

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way with my own logical tries

```css
.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 5% auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 240px;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
}
.that-circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 25px 0 #e5e5e5;
}
@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
}

.percentage {
  fill: #4285f4;
  font-size: 0.375em;
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-family: AvenirNext;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
.percentage_done {
  fill: #9b9b9b;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  font-family: AvenirNext;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
            <p class="Project_Analytics_Heading text-center">
                Time per Application
            </p>
            <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">

                <path class="that-circle" stroke="#ffba00" stroke-dasharray="100 50" d="M18 2.0845
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

                <path class="that-circle" stroke="#ff4858" stroke-dasharray="50 75" d="M18 2.0845
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

                <path class="that-circle" stroke="#845cee" stroke-dasharray="25 100" d="M18 2.0845
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

                <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">50%</text>
                <text x="13" y="25" class="percentage_done">iOS</text>

            </svg>
        </div>
```

** Example 1:===> If i have 3 elements 50, 25, 25 we have to write functionality such that from last element**

3rd element

> we have to set stroke-dasharray 25 100

---> where 25 is the value out of 100 at first attempt

2nd element

> we have to set stroke-dasharray 50 75

--> first value is 50 because (2nd element + 3rd element) ==> 25 + 25 ==> 50

--> second value is 75 because (100 - 3rd element value) ==> 100-25 ==> 75

1st element

> we have to set stroke-dasharray 100 50

--> first value is 100 because (1st element + 2nd element + 3rd element) ==> 50 + 25 + 25 ==> 100

--> second value is 50 because (100 - (2nd element + 3rd element value)) ==> 100-(25 + 25) ==> 50

** Example 2:===> If i have 4 elements 30, 20, 40, 10 we have to write functionality such that from last element**

4th element

> we have to set stroke-dasharray 10 100

---> where 10 is the value out of 100 at first attempt

3rd element

> we have to set stroke-dasharray 50 90

---> first value is 50 because (3rd element + 4th element) ==> 40 + 10 ==> 50

--> second value is 90 because (100 -  3rd element value) ==> 100-10 ==> 90

2nd element

> we have to set stroke-dasharray 70 50

--> first value is 70 because (2nd element + 3rd element + 4th element) ==> 20 + 40 + 10 ==> 70

--> second value is 50 because (100 - (3rd element value + 4th element)) ==> 100 - (40+10) ==> 50

1st element

> we have to set stroke-dasharray 100 30

--> first value is 100 because (1st element + 2nd element + 3rd element + 4th element) ==> 30+ 20 + 40 + 10 ==> 100

--> second value is 30 because (100 - (2nd element + 3rd element + 4th element value)) ==> 100-(20 + 40 + 10) ==> 30

hope you understand the logic

Comment: Thanks for description below the snippet. It helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it: I would animate the stroke-dashoffset from 50 to 0.

In your code I've changed the stroke-dasharray. In this case the first value is the length of the stroke and the second value is the length of the gap. The gap has to be big enough in order for the stroke to apear only once. In the code I use 100, the value of the perimeter.

Your first path goes last because I want it above the other 2 paths. For this path I'm using `stroke-dasharray="50,100"` The length of the stroke is 50  and the gap is 100.

For your first path I'm using `stroke-dasharray="70,100"` Why 75? 50+25 = 75. The first 50 units are under the next path. Only 25 units will remain visible.

Your last path goes first, and the `stroke-dasharray="100,100"`. 75 units of this path are now underneath the previous paths.

I hope this is what you need.

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 5% auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 240px;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
}
.that-circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dashoffset:50;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 25px 0 #e5e5e5;
}
@keyframes progress {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

}

.percentage {
  fill: #4285f4;
  font-size: 0.375em;
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-family: AvenirNext;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
.percentage_done {
  fill: #9b9b9b;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  font-family: AvenirNext;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" width="150" class="circular-chart">

               <path class="that-circle" stroke="#845cee" stroke-dasharray="100,100" d="M18 2.0845
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

                <path class="that-circle" stroke="#ff4858" stroke-dasharray="75,100"  d="M18 2.0845
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />
    
    <path class="that-circle" stroke="#ffba00" stroke-dasharray="50,100" d="M18 2.0845
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />


                <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">50%</text>
                <text x="13" y="25" class="percentage_done">iOS</text>

            </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: In current graph only 3 elements percentages are there. If suppose there are 10 elements percentages are there then how to draw the above graph. All are dynamic from api

Comment: In this case you will need to create an object with the data, But this is another question, If  you liked my answer please accept it and ask another question, I'll be glad to help,

Comment: You just created chart without any logical values

Comment: I have found a working way will update my answer after some time

Answer (score 0):

```css
.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 5% auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 240px;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
}
.that-circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 25px 0 #e5e5e5;
}
@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
}

.percentage {
  fill: #4285f4;
  font-size: 0.375em;
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-family: AvenirNext;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
.percentage_done {
  fill: #9b9b9b;
  font-size: 0.2em;
  font-family: AvenirNext;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
            <p class="Project_Analytics_Heading text-center">
                Time per Application
            </p>
            <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">

                <path class="that-circle" stroke="#ffba00" stroke-dasharray="100" d="M18 2.0845
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

                <path class="that-circle" stroke="#ff4858" stroke-dasharray="50 100" d="M18 2.0845
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

                <path class="that-circle" stroke="#845cee" stroke-dasharray="25 100" d="M18 2.0845
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

                <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">50%</text>
                <text x="13" y="25" class="percentage_done">iOS</text>

            </svg>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).